# Suggest a regex that matches a string with letters and (numbers or special characters)

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I am developing a sign-up page. In that, I want user to input password with the following format:

- Must contains a series of letters and numbers or special characters
- Order is not necessary
- Reject if the string doesn't have a letter

Example:

Valid inputs:

```
abc123 
123abc 
abc!@#
!@#abc
```

Invalid inputs:

```
abc
123    
!@#    
123!@#
```

My work:

```
((([A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9])*)(([0-9])|([[\]{}\\|;:'"_+=!@#$%$%^&*()-,<\.>/\?`~])))
```

It matches only `abc123` and `abc!@#`.

Comment: My Work 

((([A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9]))(([0-9])|([[]{}\|;:'"_+=!@#$%$%^&()-,<.>/\?`~])))

it matches only abc123,abc!@#

Comment: Is `[A-Za-z](?=[[\]{}\\|;:'"_+=!@#$%$%^&*()-,<\.>/\?\`~0-9])|(?<=[[\]{}\\|;:'"_+=!@#$%$%^&*()-,<\.>/\?\`~0-9])[A-Za-z]` fine ?

Comment: Although you can do this with a regular expression it is probably easier to just count how many letters, digits and specials you got. This would also allow more complicated rules (e.g at least 3 letters and 2 digits)

Comment: @Leyffda .. When it tested it in regexr.com , it shows "positive lookbehind not supported in this flavor of regex "

Comment: @anubhava .. Because the password must have both alphabets and numbers or special characters. Alphabets alone or numbers alone or special characters alone should be rejected

Comment: @LordCommander Please take a look at [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/48346033#48346033)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the following ?

`((([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9#]+))|(([0-9#]+)([a-zA-Z]+)))[a-zA-Z0-9#]*`

`#` being replaced by allowed special characters.

It mandates an alphabet and a special character or a number followed by any number of allowed characters

Comment: Work like charm !! Thank you very much